# WindowStartupLocation CenterOwner is only working in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf

I just stumbled over some weird behaviour in my WPF-Application.

I try to make sure, certain windows will be displayed on the same screen as their "Parent-Window".

For this I use the Window-Property `WindowStartupLocation = CenterOwner`, which is functioning as expecten when run directly **from Visual Studio**.

The Weird thig is, that when I run the exact same .exe (...\Project\bin\Debug\Project.exe) **"by Hand"**, the "Child-Window" always starts on my Main-Screen, no matter if I moved the "Parent-Window".

So when I move my "Parent-Window" to my Second-Screen, and open the "Child-Window", it will still be displayed on my Main-Screen and not, as expected, on my Second-Screen.

**So my problem is, that i get different behaviours, if I run the .exe
"by hand" or directly from Visual Studio.**

The ExtensionMethods I use:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods {
//I created these Extensions, to easily show Windows on the same screen, as a give Window.

    public static bool? ShowDialog(this Window child, Window owner) {
        child.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
        child.Owner = owner;
        return child.ShowDialog();
    }

    public static void Show(this Window child, Window owner) {
        child.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
        child.Owner = owner;
        child.Show();
    }
}
```

How I open up a new "Child-Window"

```
public void test(Window pw) {
    ChildWindow cw = new ChildWindow();
    cw.ShowDialog(pw); //Edited typo from "cw.ShowDialog(w);"
}
```

**Edit:**

I just created a fresh project, with only two Windows and the extension Methods in it, to try it out in a clean environment.

In this process i found out, that the problem only occurs, when the second Window is Maximized. Both when set `WindowState = Maximized` in xaml, or via code on the Constructor of the Child-Window.

Still, directly from Visual Studio, the behavior is just as expected, but not when directly running the .exe.

The entire Code of my "fresh" Project:

MainWindow XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Open Child" Click="btn"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication3 {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void btn(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            test(this);
        }

        public void test(Window pw) {
            ChildWindow cw = new ChildWindow();
            cw.ShowDialog(pw);
        }
    }

    public static class ExtensionMethods {
        //I created these Extensions, to easily show Windows on the same screen, as a give Window.

        public static bool? ShowDialog(this Window child, Window owner) {
            child.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
            child.Owner = owner;
            return child.ShowDialog();
        }

        public static void Show(this Window child, Window owner) {
            child.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
            child.Owner = owner;
            child.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

ChildWindow XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.ChildWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="ChildWindow" Height="300" Width="300"
        WindowState="Maximized">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="CHILD"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ChildWindow cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication3 {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für ChildWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ChildWindow : Window {
        public ChildWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are running the correct version of your .exe?

Comment: Yes I´m running the correct Version, since it´s  the only Version ^^

Comment: If it's "the only version" you have only compiled your app once. There is a new .exe being produced on each successful build. Having said that, I am afraid I cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: Ok, found new information, since you told me, you could not recreate the problem, I created a fresh new project, and wrote only the affected code. In the process I found a new peice of information, updated my answer.

Comment: Can assure that there are not typos, posted the entire code of my example project

Comment: Oh sorry, misunderstood that, yeah in the first code i posted, that was a typo on StackOverflow, the code was correct tho.

Comment: Just tested your code... Indeed, it does start on the other screen. Both in debug and release mode.

Comment: Sorry my circumstances weren`t clear enaugh, but I doesn´t differ from Debug and Release-Mode, it differs if run from VS (Debug or Release) to running the .exe myselfe directly.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with CenterOwner under VS 2019 WPF app ... works perfectly when running from VS IDE under debug and release mode. But when I deploy my application to another PC, CenterOwner behaves like CenterScreen. I have the owner defined correctly in my app and hence why it works fine under VS IDE, but not when deployed. Running Win10 19042 and latest update to VS 2019 16.8.3 ... I'm wondering if this is a .NET 4.7.2 problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tho I still don´t understand why this behaviour occurs, I still found a work around.

The problem seems to corrolate to the "Child-Window" beeing Maximized. When the WindowState is not altered, in both VS and when exetued directly, the behaviour is as expected.

My work around is, to Maximize the window, after the window is loaded, because then it alrady is on the correct screen.

Example Code in Child-Window Constructor:

```
public ChildWindow() {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.Loaded += delegate(object ds, RoutedEventArgs de) {
        ((Window)ds).WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;
    };
}
```

Still if anyone stumbles across this question an has some further information about why this problem occurs, feel free to share.

As for me, this is a minor inconveniance, but it is working, so I´m gonna go with that for now.

**Edit:**

Also for everyone interested, for even less inconvenience, I altered my ExtensionMethod a little bit:

```
public static bool? ShowDialog(this Window child, Window owner) {
    child.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
    child.Owner = owner;

    //Detects, if the Window should be Maximized. If so set the State to
    //Normal instead and add an Eventhandler to Maximize the Window after beeing loaded.
    if (child.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized) {
        child.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
        child.Loaded += delegate(object ds, RoutedEventArgs de) {
            ((Window)ds).WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;
        };
    }

    return child.ShowDialog();
}
```

This way, you can set the WindowState in XMAL, as usual, and don´t need to explicitly set in the loaded event yourself.